# Error "Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()" while trying delete a row in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, methods

My method to delete an image from database and local storage.

```
public function destroy($id) {
        $image = DB::table('images')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        //print_r($image);
        //return 'end';
        File::delete(public_path() . '/images/gallery/thumb-' . $image->path);
        File::delete(public_path() . '/images/gallery/' . $image->path);
        $image->delete();
        return Redirect::back()
                        ->with('form_success', 1)
                        ->with('form_message', 'Image successfully deleted!');
    }
```

If I try to return value of `$image` I get:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 49 [site_id] => 1 [page_id] => [location] => gallery [alt] => [path] => 60e52a2755ffe8923d5ac1232f5d9154.jpg )
```

So what's wrong with my code? Now my Laravel version is 4.2.1, but i try to downgrade him to 4.1.17, but no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code according the following and I hope that your problem will be solved..

```
public function destroy($id) {
        $query = DB::table('images')->where('id', '=', $id);
        $image = $query->first();
        //print_r($image);
        //return 'end';
        File::delete(public_path() . '/images/gallery/thumb-' . $image->path);
        File::delete(public_path() . '/images/gallery/' . $image->path);
        $query->delete();
        return Redirect::back()
                        ->with('form_success', 1)
                        ->with('form_message', 'Image successfully deleted!');
    }
```

first() and delete() these functions execute the code.So first assign your conditions to a variable and then execute them separately.Thanks

Answer (score 15):

The problem is once you call `first()`, the query is executed and the results are returned.  You will have to call `delete()` before you call `first()`.

`DB::table('images')->where('id', $id)->delete();`

Since you are using the query builder, you are going to get back `stdClass` objects (which do not have delete methods) as you've seen rather than the models you'd usually get when using Eloquent.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine for me. But if I need to get value of this $image and delete it after some actions? I need to make 2 queries?

Comment: Yeah, one for the select and one for the delete.  I don't think there is a query which can both select and return the results and delete the record in one shot.

Comment: why? I want to delete the first one not every match