# “Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()” error while trying delete a row in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

Having an issue with deleting a row from a table.

The issue seems really similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994179/error-call-to-undefined-method-stdclassdelete-while-trying-delete-a-row-in), however it didn't solve the problem.

My controller function is as follows:

```
public function favourites() {

        //get relevant data for DB insert
        $spot_id = Input::get('spot_id');
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        //query DB if favourite exists
        $query = DB::table('favourites')
            ->where('spot_id', '=', $spot_id)
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);

        $check_favourites = $query->first();

        if (is_null($check_favourites)) {
            //doesnt exist - create record
            $favourite              = new Favourite;
            $favourite->spot_id     = $spot_id;
            $favourite->user_id     = $user_id;
            $favourite->save();

            //return ajax true
            return json_encode(true);               

        } else {
            // exists - delete record
            $check_favourites->delete();
            //return ajax false
            return json_encode(false);      
        }

}
```

I'm using Laravel 4.2

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use Eloquent `delete()` method you need to use [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/eloquent), not [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/queries).

Instead of:

```
//query DB if favourite exists
$query = DB::table('favourites')
    ->where('spot_id', '=', $spot_id)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);

$check_favourites = $query->first();
```

Should be:

```
$check_favourites = Favourite::where('spot_id', '=', $spot_id)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->first();
```

---

> Note: All methods available on the query builder are also available
>   when querying Eloquent models.

Comment: i thought it might be something silly. worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, either @limonte's answer (which I would prefer) or using the id to run the delete query:

```
DB::table('favourites')->delete($check_favourites->id);
```